# set.seed() backward compatibilty R 3.5.3 and 3.6?

Tags: r

obviously the random generator was changed from 3.5.3 to 3.6 internally.

If found that I can get 3.5.3 results with the following under 3.6:
RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")

But what's with the other direction?
I have create a sample dataset under 3.6 and had to do a fall back to 3.5.3 because some libraries were not available.

How can I recreate to 3.6 results with R 3.5.3?

Thx

Comment: I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. You should focus on building those packages for R 3.6. That should be easier.

Comment: Thanks. I have found that backward compatibility is not there. sample.kind is not available with 3.5.3...